# What happens to data in an iOS app when new app version upgrade and new iOS version upgrade

Tags: ios

My understanding of what happens to app data in each of the app folders is outlined below, can somebody confirm that I'm correct and if not, where to find Apple documentation on it. I'm having trouble finding enough information to verify.

My understanding is limited on what happens to data when the user upgrades their iOS. Is the data in folders that are backed up by iTunes/iCloud the only safe places for data? Meaning data in /Tmp and /Library/Caches will not be there once the user upgrades their iOS?

/Documents:

- iOS will back-up data via iTunes/iCloud? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after new app version release? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after iOS upgrade? Yes

/Library:

- iOS will back-up data via iTunes/iCloud? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after new app version release? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after iOS upgrade? Yes

/Library/Caches:

- iOS will back-up data via iTunes/iCloud? No
- iOS guarantees data restoration after new app version release? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after iOS upgrade? No

/Library/Preferences:

- iOS will back-up data via iTunes/iCloud? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after new app version release? Yes
- iOS guarantees data restoration after iOS upgrade? Yes

/Tmp:

- iOS will back-up data via iTunes/iCloud? No
- iOS guarantees data restoration after new app version release? No
- iOS guarantees data restoration after iOS upgrade? No

Comment: and, your programming question is?

Comment: if I had to guess it's "Is this correct?"

Answer (score 1):

This is broadly correct, however after iOS5, the contents of Library/Caches can be erased at any time if the OS decides that it's running low on disk space, so it's a bad idea to store anything in there long-term.

If you want to store cache data permanently on the device, but not have it backed up to iCloud, there is a new property called NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey that can be set on a file or folder located anywhere in Library or Documents that will prevent it from being backed up to iCloud.

I've written a simple library that manages the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey for you, and provides constants for all of these folders with more meaningful names so it's easier to remember which ones to use for which purpose:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/StandardPaths

Comment: One comment - on application upgrade, all the absolute paths are changed because the app is moved to a different folder.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You shouldn't save these paths in a file or in the NSUserDefaults, you should always call the method again to re-generate the path if you need to access a previously saved file.